# getColumnCount does not count the column when its value is null?

Tags: java, sql, json, null

I have this code:

```
// Get the results
while(rs.next())
{
    resultList = new JSONObject();
    for(int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        resultList.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i) , rs.getString(i));
    }
}
```

It appears that rsmd.getColumnCount() does not count the columns for which the corresponding value is null. Is there any workaround for this ?

Depending on the time of the day, the same SQL returns values and/or nulls and I would like to get the same number of columns each time.

Cheers,
Tim

---

This is JAVA of course - and I used the "Null" tag because the getColumnCount tag was refused because I am lacking "reputation points" on this site.

I think getColumnCount is not counting the null entries because I have 2 entries in my DB, one with a few null entries and the other one with no null entries.

getColumnCount only returns the count for entries with actual values.

Comment: null is not a proper tag

Comment: Why do you think it isn't counting it? Could the symptom you're seeing be caused by something else? Java's getColumnCount on ResultSetMetaData should return the same count regardless of NULLs as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved: The problem was not `getColumnCount()`, but the

```
   resultList.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i) , rs.getString(i));
```

The Put method did not add anything when `rs.getString(i)` returned `null`.
What induced me into error was that a print of these values did show the `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put some flag on your query? If it's null then put something and you can catch these on your code.

Comment: something like: case when Column is null then -1

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but it is not related to nulls, I just get a totally wrong answer back from getColumnCount().  My workaround uses a separate ResultSet, thusly:

```
// Get the results
DatabaseMetaData metadata = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

int columnCount = 0;
try {
     metadata = connection.getMetaData();
     rs = metadata.getColumns(null, "YOURSCHEMA", "YOURTABLE", null);
     while (column.next()) {
          columnCount++;
     }
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

/* note here you must re-fill your rs or create a new one since it cannot be reset
 with a call to rs.first() as it is a forward-only collection, with something like */

// rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM yourschema.yourtable");

while(rs.next())
{
    resultList = new JSONObject();
    for(int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        resultList.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i) , rs.getString(i));
    }
}
```